# MCP2210 DLL on mac

Tags: python, macos, dll, ctypes

For a project I use a MCP2210. On the website of microchip I found the DLL file. Now I want to try to write some python code on macOS but the dLL file is only for windows. Is there a way to convert te DLL for macOS? Or are there other solutions for this?

I try to import the file with 
mcp_dll = ctypes.CDLL("Path_to_dll.dll")

Comment: No, .dll is a windows specific format and you'd need a version for macOS.

Comment: so what is the equivalent for mac? and how do you import that into python

Comment: You'd want a .so file for macos (and linux).

Comment: Is there a .so file for the MCP2210?

Comment: If you go to the download page and click on "Linux library" you get this: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP2210_linux_library.zip

Comment: I found that already. but what specific file i have to import in python to have it work?